# REGEX Exclude First Dash

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am attempting to use the REGEXP_MATCH, REGEXP_EXTRACT functions in tableau to isolate 'designated port' from a data set.

I am having a horrible time with the entries that have a leading '-', I have tried the following and the best I can get is the 4 digit with the leading "-", which I do not want. I want it to return digit-digit with as many digits as meets that criteria.

first solution:

```
(\d*-\d*)*
```

second solution:

```
(\d*-(\d*-\d*-\d*-\d*))
```

third solution (only returns on '1-1-1-1' format, matches as -1-1-1-1):

```
([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})
```

Data sample:

```
NETWORK-1-1-1-1
ACCESS-1-1-1-1
FA0/1
GE-0/2/3
XE-2/1/10
GI0/0/1
GIGABIT ETHERNET 1-1-2
1-1-2-100
1-1-2-10.943
```

Desired Isolation (In Bold)

NETWORK-**1-1-1-1**

ACCESS-**1-1-1-1**

FA0/1

GE-0/2/3

XE-2/1/10

GI0/0/1

GIGABIT ETHERNET **1-1-2**

**1-1-2-100**

**1-1-2-10**.943

Desired Return

```
1-1-1-1
1-1-1-1
excluded
excluded
excluded
excluded
1-1-2
1-1-2-100
1-1-2-10
```

Tableau Formula with Regex match and extract:

```
IF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')

ELSE NULL
END
```

Tableau Results:

```
1-1-1-1
1-1-1-1
0/1
0/2/3
2/1/10
0/0/1
1-1-2
1-1-2-100
1-1-2-10
```

Comment: Try `(\d+(?:-\d+)+)`

Comment: that 100% worked on regex101, but broke and failed in tableau. Huge progress though so thanks

Comment: Ok, then try `(\d+(-\d+)+)` or `(\d+-\b[-0-9]+\b)`

Comment: the first one did it. You're a wizard 'arry!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{1,3}` instead of `{0,3}`.

Comment: ([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})

changed to

([0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3})

returns 

-1-1-1 instead of -1-1-1-3

Answer (score 0):

got a solution through DM from Wiktor, works beautifully

```
(\d+(-\d+)+)
```

previous code

```
IF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d{0,3}\/\d{0,3})')


ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'([0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,3})')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(-[0-9]{0,3})')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(-[0-9]{0,3})')

ELSE NULL
END
```

New Improved and WORKING code

```
IF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d+(\/\d+)+)')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d+(\/\d+)+)')

ELSEIF REGEXP_MATCH([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d+(-\d+)+)')
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Port Access Less VLAN],'(\d+(-\d+)+)')

ELSE NULL
END
```